# How to get the properties of the shortest path between 2 vertexes

Tags: orientdb

I am using Java, and I want to get the property" name "of each vertex of the shortest path between #26:1 and #24.0 . I am using the sql command select dijkstra (#26:1,#24.0,"distance") from V. And I get the result OResultSet. I dont know how the get the rid of each vertex in my java program (I mean OVertex or ORID of each vertex : objects offered by orientdb in my java program) .

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste code as pictures. Insert the code into the question with an indent of 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

try to do it with following code:

```
String query3 = "SELECT dijkstra (#26:1, #28:1, 'valeur') FROM V";

OResultSet rs3 = db.query(query3);

while(rs3.hasNext()) {
      OResult row = rs3.next();
      String rid= row.getProperty("@rid");
}
rs3.close();
```

For more information, you can look for in [official java-api](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/Java-Query-API.html)

I hope it will help you!

Comment: I Splited the resultSet

Comment: so what did u get? can u paste your result here please?